# Prestashop - Function Generate

Tags: prestashop

I have create hook with hookActionCustomerAccountAdd.It 's work fine.
But i have :
$code_client = self::generateCode();

```
public  function generateCode()
{   

      $last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
      SELECT MAX(code)
      FROM ps_customer_code');
      echo ("<br>".$last_id."<br/>\n");
      return str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 8, 'FG000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

but the retrun of this function working => all the time i have FG000001 but the last_id it good.
How can i fixed this bug?!

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you please rephrase it ?

Comment: Hi, i have add a table with id (auto-incr) and code. and i want this code be FG000000 for the fisrt ,and the second record with FG000001 ... => then a Function

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed:
i must get the id of the last record then add it to my field
So the function becomes:
public  function generateCode()
{

```
  $last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
  SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM ps_customer_code');
  echo ("<br>".$last_id."<br/>\n");
  return str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 8, 'FG000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

}
after that we get the code from the function:
$code_client = self::generateCode();